# jQuery(document).ready doesn't run under IIS7

Tags: jquery, iis-7, document-ready

To simplify this test case, I created a new default .NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2010, and added the following code to the HTML header in Site.Master:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert('jQuery document ready'); });
</script>
```

This works as expected in the .NET development server. However, when deployed to IIS7, the jQuery(document).ready function is not executed. Needless to say, my actual application is much more complicated. This eliminates all "suspects" except IIS7 deployment.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: What do you get if you remove all of the javascript, and replace it with `alert($);`? Another alternative would be to load jQuery from an absolute URL, such as Google's hosted version: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js - your problem may be with directory layouts.

Comment: Does it work in Firefox?

Comment: Download something called httpwatch and see if jQuery is being downloaded. Remember that this is something that happens client side, so IIS should have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably caused by the src reference to

```
src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"
```

Replace it with:

```
src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js")%>"
```

If your site is deployed in a virtual directory this is probably the case.

Comment: BINGO! That's it. When I looked in the inetpub log file, there was an error on "GET /Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" IIS wasn't resolving the relative link properly. Many thanks.