# asp.net mvc3 website on IIS 7.5 website not loading jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iis-7, razor

Newbie here on jQuery struggling with some deployment essentials:

Working with the default asp.net mvc3 template that comes with VS2010, I tried to include the jquery ui selectable widget.  In the header section of _Layout.cshtml, I have the following possibilities:

```
    @* <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
   @* <script src="@Url.Content("http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
    @*    <script src="@Url.Content("http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
    <script src="@Url.Content("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I cannot get any of these scripts to load, as widget does not display on the site within IIS.  Within Visual Studio, I can see jQuery content.

I have looked through all IIS settings for the site but nothing appears to be javascript related.  I read the following related posts:

- [jQuery(document).ready does not run under iis 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715098/jquerydocument-ready-doesnt-run-under-iis7)
- [jQuery library location wants to be referenced differently on
  server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730336/jquery-library-location-wants-to-be-referenced-differently-on-server)

which does not seem to be the case here as I have tried absolute paths with the correct Url.Content syntax.  Probably missing something but what could it be?

**EDIT 1**
Changed load minified version of jQuery from google to see if this is the problem.

Comment: If you check in Firebug, is the jquery/jquery ui scripts being loaded correctly? Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Try running the site on chrome with the developer tools window open.  You will be able to see if the files are loading or not.  It may not be an IIS config issue at all.

Comment: @Rory, console in IE9 debug tools does not show any script loading issues besides" SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited. "
Neither does IIS logs.

Comment: @Brian. I am looking at the network traffic through IE9 debugging tools and it shows the script being retrieved as follows: URL Method Result Type Received Taken Initiator Wait‎‎ Start‎‎ Request‎‎ Response‎‎ Cache read‎‎ Gap‎‎
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js GET 304 text/javascript 240 B 47 ms <script> 62 0 47 0 0 1903
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js GET 304 text/javascript 429 B 47 ms <script> 62 0 47 0 0 1903.

Answer (score 2):

When you are referencing items on another domain you don't need the HTML Helper `@Url.Content()` Try just using the URL without the helper.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also if you can post a link to the site or the raw HTML that is rendered in the browser we can determine quickly what is happening.

Comment: Using URL with helper does not seem to be the problem as looking at source through IE9 dubgging tools shows that the HTML Helper is stripped out and src points to correct destination.  Also, I will be using scrips once I figure out what is going on with the script loading in general.  Unfortunately site is not yet public so cannot post a link.  I am testing this on my local IIS.

Comment: One thing, you don't need to specify http: or https:, if you use "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" it will use what ever the current schema is (http or https). Thats not your issue but thought I would point you to that. I would use Fiddler or the Net tab in Firefox to watch individual file requests and see if any are hanging for what ever reason

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the response.  After further digging, it turns out that this is not a jQuery loading issue after all.  Scripts are being loaded correctly. If I hardcode the children of the jQuery selectable like so

```
<ol id="selectable">
                <li class="ui-state-default">test</li>
            </ol>
```

it loads under IIS.

However, jQuery selectable is given children dynamically in the following ajax snippet:

```
  function GetBusRoutes(parameters) {
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                 url: "/home/GetAvailableRoutes",  
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                dataType: "json", 
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }, 
                success: function (msg) {
                    var selectable = $('#selectable');
                    $.each(msg, function(i, route) {
                        selectable.append($('<li/>', { "class": "ui-state-default", text: route.Name}));
                    });
                } 

         });
     }
```

and the HTTP GET request if failing with a 404 as it is trying to resolve the url  to http://localhost:80/home/GetAvailableRoutes instead of invoking my controller action, which is what happens when site runs under Visual Studio.  Will post another question on this if I cannot figure out correct syntax to pass to the ajax url.